# span is not responding

Tags: html, css

I need the span to go up when focusing on an input or its validity, but it doesn't react to styles at all
HTML:

```
<div class="login">
        <span class="logtxt">Никнейм или почта</span>
        <input type="text" name="log" id="log" class="loginput" required="required">
    </div>
```

CSS:

````
    position: relative;
    display: flex;
}
.loginput{
    padding: 10px;
    margin-bottom: 10px;
}
.logtxt{
    position: absolute;
    pointer-events: none;
    left: 12px;
    color: gray;
    transition: all ease-in-out .4s;
    padding: 10px;
}
.loginput:valid ~ .logtxt{
    font-size: 2px;
}```
````

Answer (score 0):

Use the *[focus](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/:focus)* pseudo-class and changing the bottom (you can use either top or bottom) is the key.

```css
.login {
  position: relative;
  display: flex;
}

.loginput {
  padding: 15px;
  margin-bottom: 10px;
}

.logtxt {
  position: absolute;
  pointer-events: none;
  left: 12px;
  color: gray;
  transition: all ease-in-out .4s;
  padding: 5px;
  /* IMPORTATN  */
  bottom: 22.5px;
  background-color: #fff
}

.loginput:valid~.logtxt {
  bottom: 40px;
  font-size: 12px
}

 /* IMPORTATN  */
.loginput:focus ~ .logtxt {
  bottom: 40px;
  font-size: 12px
}
```

```html
<div class="login">
  
  <input type="text" name="log" id="log" class="loginput" required="required">
  <span class="logtxt">Никнейм или почта</span>
</div>
```